# How to make a link send parameter to the jquery function which then calls ajax function to load?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm searching for this question for all day long, and tried out every other variation as I can, but I can not make following code work. How to make a link send parameter to the jquery function which then calls ajax function to load data from REST API? I don't want link to open new page, but want to load data on the same page. e.preventDefault does not work at all. So, can't see any ajax activity.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $("$decklist").bind("click", function(event) {

    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    alert("loading via proxy: " + url);
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/flashcardapp/webservices/flashcardapp/",
        data: "url="+url, 
        success: function(data){
          alert("finally got data " + data);
        }
      });
    event.preventDefault();
 });

});
```

Comment: You are using `$` in jquery selector..i think it's wrong.

Comment: What you're asking is so confusing. You are trying to make an ajax request. What are you trying to in addition to that?

Answer (score 0):

It might just be a typo. Try `#` instead of `$` in your jQuery selector (the decklist). Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // HERE. Notice how it says #decklist below and not $decklist
    $("#decklist").bind("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // ... the rest of your code
    });
});
```

Also we don't have your HTML in here but I assume your link looks something like this (with an `id` attribute). Make sure `id="decklist"` and not something like `id="$decklist"`.

```
<a href="#" id="decklist">Something</a>
```